# How to make urls non-editable in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

New to rails. I am passing a bunch of params using url to a form page. The form page captures these params and prompts user to enter a few more fields using a typical form based entry system. However, when I change one of the url params, it changes the value automatically stored in the form. I dont want this to happen - is there a way to make the params passed through urls non-editable?

Answer (score 1):

Urls don't work that way, you can't prevent them from being changed. Sounds to me like you may want to redesign how you pass in the variables to the form, e.g. maybe a `POST`?

Comment: A few parameters in my form are to be filled by the user and a few get auto populated by capturing the params. How can I use POST in such a case?

Comment: @RahulPoddar You can't. If the populated data is passed in from your app, use an instance variable instead of `params`. It will "hide" the data from plain sight, but it will not protect it. Client-side data is **always** editable.